# XML output with nested query for xml explicit or path

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I wrote a query today in T-sql that is completely functional. For a customer I need to deliver the data in XML format. I tried to do it with the explicit method and the path method without any succes.

My query is the following :

```
select 
    allShopsItem.ShopCode as ShopCode
    , allShopsItem.ItemCode as ItemCode
    , allShopsItem.SupplyNumber as SupplyNumber
    , CONVERT (date, GETDATE()-1) as Fulldate
    , isnull(sales.SumQtyTransactions, 0) as Sales
    , isnull(stock.Qty, 0) as Stock
    , isnull(outstandingorders.sumQTY, 0) as Outstanding
from (
        select 
            S.SHOP_CODE as ShopCode, 
            I.ITEM_CODE as ItemCode,
            I.ITEM_NAME as ItemName,
            CVI.CUSTVENDRELATION as SupplyNumber
        from 
            BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S
            CROSS JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM I
            INNER JOIN BI_STAGING.ERP_CUSTVENDEXTERNALITEM CVI
            ON I.ITEM_CODE = CVI.ITEMID AND CVI.CUSTVENDRELATION = 900520
        WHERE 
            I.ITEM_GRP_CODE = 'HW-ACC' /*and I.ITEM_CYCLE = 'Normaal'*/ and I.ROW_IS_CURRENT = 1 
            AND S.SHOP_TYPE IN ('Telenet Store','Telenet Concept Store')
            AND S.SHOP_IS_CLOSED = 0
        ) as allShopsItem
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            S.SHOP_CODE as ShopCode, 
            I.ITEM_CODE as ItemCode,
            CAST(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUANTITY*-1) AS INTEGER) as SumQtyTransactions
        FROM 
            BI_DWH_BC.F_TRANSACTION TR
                INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_DATE D ON D.PK_DATE = TR.FK_TRANS_DATE
                INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S ON S.PK_SHOP = TR.FK_TRANS_SHOP
                INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM I ON I.PK_ITEM = TR.FK_TRANS_ITEM
        WHERE
            D.DATE_FULLDATE = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()-1)  
            --TR.FK_TRANS_DATE = 20140702  
        GROUP BY 
            S.SHOP_CODE, I.ITEM_CODE
                ) as sales ON allShopsItem.ShopCode = sales.ShopCode AND allShopsItem.ItemCode = sales.ItemCode

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            S.SHOP_CODE as ShopCode
            , IT.ITEM_CODE as ItemCode
            , SUM(SM.STMOV_QTY) Qty
        FROM BI_DWH_BC.F_STOCK_MOVEMENT SM
            INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_DATE D ON D.PK_DATE = SM.FK_STMOV_DATE
            INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM IT ON IT.PK_ITEM = SM.FK_STMOV_ITEM
            INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S ON S.PK_SHOP = SM.FK_STMOV_SHOP
        WHERE 
            D.DATE_FULLDATE <= CONVERT (date, GETDATE()-1)  
        GROUP BY 
            S.SHOP_CODE, IT.ITEM_CODE
        HAVING 
            SUM(SM.STMOV_QTY) <> 0
                )  as stock ON allShopsItem.ShopCode = stock.ShopCode AND allShopsItem.ItemCode = stock.ItemCode

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            S.SHOP_CODE as ShopCode, 
            PL.ITEMID  as ItemID,
            SUM(CAST(PL.REMAINPURCHPHYSICAL AS INTEGER)) as sumQTY
        FROM 
            BI_STAGING.ERP_PURCHLINE PL
                INNER JOIN BI_STAGING.ERP_PURCHTABLE PT ON PT.PURCHID = PL.PURCHID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_STAGING.ERP_VENDTABLECUBE V ON PT.INVOICEACCOUNT = V.ACCOUNTNUM
                LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S ON S.SHOP_CODE = RIGHT(PT.INVENTLOCATIONID,3)
        WHERE 
            PL.REMAINPURCHPHYSICAL <> 0 AND PL.QTYORDERED <> 0
        GROUP BY 
            S.SHOP_CODE, PL.ITEMID
                ) as outstandingorders ON allShopsItem.ShopCode = outstandingorders.ShopCode AND allShopsItem.ItemCode = outstandingorders.ItemID

GROUP BY 
    allShopsItem.ShopCode, allShopsItem.ItemCode,allShopsItem.SupplyNumber, sales.SumQtyTransactions, stock.Qty, outstandingorders.sumQTY
ORDER BY 
    allShopsItem.ShopCode, allShopsItem.ItemCode
```

The  output of the following query can be compared by the following example:

```
shopcode  itemcode  Sales  Stock
--------  --------  -----  -----
0013       121212     2      1
0013       122224     3      2
0032       121545     1      1
0032       121211     2      5
```

Now I want the following xml:

```
<shopcode>
    <itemcode>
        <sales>
        </sales>
        <stock>
        </stock>
    </itemcode>
     <itemcode>
        <sales>
        </sales>
        <stock>
        </stock>
    </itemcode>
</shopcode>
```

In short words I want an overview of all my items for each shop.
Does anybody know how I can do this in a relative easy way with some adjustments in my query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom's answer looks good. As an alternative, you could encapsulate your original humungous query without xml directives as a view or CTE, and then query over that to shape the xml. Like Tom mentioned, your sample output does not quite make sense in terms of shopcode and item code, but you can tweak from here. Also, I wrapped your output in a root node:

```
;WITH SRC(shopcode, itemcode, sales, stock) AS
(
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT shopcode, itemcode, sales, stock 
    FROM <MyHumungousViewOrQuery>
   ORDER BY shopcode, itemcode
),
SHOPS(shopcode) AS (SELECT DISTINCT shopcode FROM SRC)

SELECT  shopcode AS [@code],
        (
        SELECT itemcode AS [@code],
               (
               SELECT sales AS [sales],
                      stock AS [stock]
                  FROM SRC details WHERE details.shopcode = items.shopcode AND details.itemcode = items.itemcode
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ) 
          FROM SRC items WHERE items.shopcode = SHOPS.shopcode
           FOR XML PATH('itemcode'), TYPE
        )
  FROM SHOPS
   FOR XML PATH('shopcode'), ROOT('shops')
```

Yields:

```
<shops>
  <shopcode code="0013">
    <itemcode code="121212">
      <sales>2</sales>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </itemcode>
    <itemcode code="122224">
      <sales>3</sales>
      <stock>2</stock>
    </itemcode>
  </shopcode>
  <shopcode code="0032">
    <itemcode code="121545">
      <sales>1</sales>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </itemcode>
    <itemcode code="121211">
      <sales>2</sales>
      <stock>5</stock>
    </itemcode>
  </shopcode>
</shops>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure exactly how you want the XML structured (e.g. do you need the shop/item codes as attributes?), but something like this might work for you..

```sql
SELECT
    S.SHOP_CODE AS [@code],
    (
        SELECT
            ITEM_CODE AS [@code],
            (
                SELECT ISNULL((
                    SELECT CAST(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUANTITY * -1) AS INT)
                    FROM BI_DWH_BC.F_TRANSACTION TR
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_DATE D
                        ON D.PK_DATE = TR.FK_TRANS_DATE
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S2
                        ON S2.PK_SHOP = TR.FK_TRANS_SHOP
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM I2
                        ON I2.PK_ITEM = TR.FK_TRANS_ITEM
                    WHERE D.DATE_FULLDATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()-1)  
                    AND S2.SHOP_CODE = S.SHOP_CODE
                    AND I2.ITEM_CODE = I.ITEM_CODE
                    GROUP BY S2.SHOP_CODE, I2.ITEM_CODE                 
                ), 0)
                FOR XML PATH ('sales'), TYPE
            ),
            (
                SELECT ISNULL((
                    SELECT
                        SUM(SM.STMOV_QTY) Qty
                    FROM BI_DWH_BC.F_STOCK_MOVEMENT SM
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_DATE D2
                        ON D2.PK_DATE = SM.FK_STMOV_DATE
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM IT
                        ON IT.PK_ITEM = SM.FK_STMOV_ITEM
                    INNER JOIN BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S2
                        ON S2.PK_SHOP = SM.FK_STMOV_SHOP
                    WHERE D2.DATE_FULLDATE <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()-1)  
                    AND S2.SHOP_CODE = S.SHOP_CODE
                    AND IT.ITEM_CODE = I.ITEM_CODE
                    GROUP BY S2.SHOP_CODE, IT.ITEM_CODE
                    HAVING SUM(SM.STMOV_QTY) <> 0
                ), 0)
                FOR XML PATH('stock'), TYPE
            )
        FROM BI_DWH_BC.D_ITEM I
        INNER JOIN BI_STAGING.ERP_CUSTVENDEXTERNALITEM CVI
            ON I.ITEM_CODE = CVI.ITEMID
            AND CVI.CUSTVENDRELATION = 900520
        WHERE I.ITEM_GRP_CODE = 'HW-ACC'
        AND I.ROW_IS_CURRENT = 1
        FOR XML PATH('item'), TYPE
    )
FROM BI_DWH_BC.D_SHOP S
WHERE S.SHOP_TYPE IN ('Telenet Store','Telenet Concept Store')
AND S.SHOP_IS_CLOSED = 0
FOR XML PATH('shop')
```

Output:

```
<shop code="13">
  <item code="121212">
    <sales>0</sales>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </item>
  <item code="122224">
    <sales>0</sales>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </item>
</shop>
<shop code="32">
  <item code="121212">
    <sales>0</sales>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </item>
  <item code="122224">
    <sales>0</sales>
    <stock>0</stock>
  </item>
</shop>
```